# How to Apply Animations to Player in Unity

Tags: android, android-animation, unity-game-engine

Hey guys so Im making my first app. I know this is a pretty loaded question but Im having a hard time following examples because the script code is different. I am making a 2D platform runner. To start, I created the platforms, environment as well as a majority if not all of the physics. The player at this point is just a circle (just a place holder). The circle can move from left to right and jump. I have now, created an actual player sprite and made animations for walking, jumping and idle. How do I apply the new sprite animations to the current circle placeholder as well as the script? My next step is to go into the animator and start making transitions i guess. Im just not sure how to add the animations to my current script. I knew this was going to be a challenge and if there is any other info you need, please let me know. Thanks so much guys.

This is my "Controls.cs" that is currently attached to my circle player/placeholder. My CheckGround is attached to him. Everything else should be in relation to the platforms he is jumping on and I dont think will change. Again, I have a sprite walking, jumping and idle that I would like to take place of the current circle/placeholder. I need the walking animation to take place when the left and right arrows are pressed, the pump animation to play when the jump button is pressed and idle animation to play when the player is just standing still otherwise. Again, thanks so much guys!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Controls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float movespeed;
    public float jumpheight;
    public bool moveright;
    public bool moveleft;
    public bool jump;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool onGround;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {



        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);

        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed, rb.velocity.y);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (onGround)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpheight);
            }
        }

        if (jump)
        {
            if (onGround)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpheight);
            }
            jump = false;
        }

        if (moveright)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if (moveleft)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-movespeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [Animation Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html). After you create it you can grab Animator from your gameObject like `transform.GetComponent<Animator>()`
Later you can blend your animations or just play them. Unity give you even possibility to make input conditions to play your animations so to be honest you don't even have to type too much code.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use an Animation Controller.
Have a look at this video - I'm following this tutorial at the moment.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0IVZhHNarg

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Sorry it took a while to get back to you. I started following that tutorial now and its working very well!